# Bubble sort in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist, xcode4.2, bubble-sort

here is my question: I have a `plist` with some objects in it. These objects have some `keys` like "age", "sex" ,"person" and etc. If `values` of these `keys` are suitable for my `if statement`, I add this object in my `array`.

Then, when my array is finally full of some suitable objects I would like to check one more key of every object - "minimumCost" which type is `NSNumber` and then sort objects from the cheapest to the most expensive objects. And I don't know how to do that. Could you give me some ideas, code or solutions please?

**Here is my code:**

```
-(NSMutableArray*)creatingList:(NSMutableArray *)array
    {
        NSDictionary  *mainDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gifts" ofType:@"txt"]];

        //---enumerate through the dictionary objects inside the rootDictionary
        NSEnumerator *enumerator = [mainDictionary objectEnumerator];
        id returnValue;

        while ((returnValue = [enumerator nextObject])) 
        {
          // Big if statement comes

          if (([[returnValue valueForKey:@"sex"]isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sex]] ||
                [[returnValue valueForKey:@"sex"]isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]) && 
                [[returnValue valueForKey:@"person"]isEqualToString:person] &&
                age >= [[returnValue valueForKey:@"minAge"] intValue] &&
                age <= [[returnValue valueForKey:@"maxAge"] intValue])

            {  
                [array addObject:[returnValue valueForKey:@"name"]];                  
            }
        }

        for (int n = 0; n < [array count];n++)
        {
           //   WHAT CODE SHOULD BE HERE ?
        }

   return array;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This does not look like a homework, so why bubble sort then?

Comment: Because I would like to sort objects by value of "minimumCost". I would like to see the cheapest at the beginning of the array and the most expansive at the end. So, thats why I called it like this.

Comment: Bubble sort is a rather inefficient sorting algorithm used almost exclusively for teaching programming. `NSMutableArray` can be sorted on any combination of properties of your object using efficient built-in facilities of the cocoa library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in `NSArray` sorting methods to accomplish this, rather than rolling your own.

See more here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/03/nsarray-sorting-using-selectors/

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use these methods.

Comment: But how can I use these methods if I want to sort objects by their keys values?

Comment: @SmartTree: The first example in Ben's link is exactly what you want.  But you onlty need one sort descriptor and the key should be `@"minimumCost"` if that is the name of the property / getter method.

Comment: But I use `NSMutableArray`, and thats why I get warning at the end of the function, when it returns a mutableArray. 
`@"minimumCost"` is one of the keys of the object. And I wanna sort these objects depending on the `value` of "minimumCost" (NSNumber).
Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: @SmartTree this is exactly how sorting arrays works.  You give it a sort descriptor that tells it how to compare the elements in the array.  Read the docs on sorting and you can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Please find the below code this is the implementation of Bubble sort with Objective-c :**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *unsortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"4",@"7",@"3",@"2",@"10",@"8",nil];
    [self bubbleSort:unsortedArray];
  }
```

**Implementation:**

```
- (NSArray *)bubbleSort:(NSMutableArray *)sortedArray
{
   long count = sortedArray.count;

   bool swapped = YES;

   while (swapped)
   {
   swapped = NO;

      for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
      {
          int x = [sortedArray[i-1] intValue];
          int y = [sortedArray[i] intValue];

          if (x > y)
          {
               [sortedArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:(i-1) withObjectAtIndex:i];
               swapped = YES;
          }
      }
   }
   return sortedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way to do an unoptimized bubble sort on an NSMutableArray of integers.

```
  NSMutableArray <NSNumber *>*foo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@9,@8,@7,@6,@5,@4]];
  for (int i = 0; i < [foo count]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < [foo count] - 1; j++) {
      if (foo[j + 1].integerValue < foo[j].integerValue) {
        NSInteger a = foo[j].integerValue;
        foo[j] = foo[j + 1];
        foo[j + 1] = @(a);
      }
    }
  }
```